# Нахождение первого символа строки. Python

Tags: python

С помощью какой функции можно как-то считать первую букву строки? К примеру: У нас есть переменная a, содержащая строку `Евгений`. 
Мне нужно, чтобы первая буква была считана какой то функцией и передана в другую переменную. Что я хочу осуществить:

```
c = 'Евгений'
... 
if первая буква переменной a == 'c':
    print("первая буква:", 'c')
```

Надеюсь меня поймут...

Comment: Вопросы желательно задавать при условии, что вы хотя бы как-то пытались решить вашу проблему. Изучить простейшие основы синтаксиса Python и его возможностей простым языком можно, введя в поисковую строку "самоучитель python" и перейдя по первой не рекламной ссылке. Если вы способны осилить технический английский язык, всё еще проще: прочитайте официальную документацию на сайте, где качали сам python. При наличии стремления решить проблему, вопроса бы у вас не возникло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = 'Евгений'
a = 'Е'

if a == c[0]:
    print(f"Первая буква: {c[0]}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы учебник читать пробовали? А Гууглить самостоятельно?

```
s="Первая буква имени"
c = s[0]
print("первая буква:", c)

первая буква: П
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого не нужна функция, можно взять первый символ строки с помощью обращения к индеску строки:

```
s = "Евгений"
print(s[0]) # вывести нулевой символ строки s
```

Результат:

```
Е
```